# Redirecting Domain to Subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have this on my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/real-estate [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /real-estate/$1 [L]
```

I want to redirect the user

```
mydomain.com -> mydomain.com/real-estate
www.mydomain.com - > www.mydomain.com/real-estate
www.mydomain.com/abc - > www.mydomain.com/real-estate/abc
and so on...
```

`mydomain.com` is properly redirecting to `mydomain.com/real-estate`

The problem are the following

`www.mydomain.com` is redirecting to `www.mydomain/home4/xxxxx/public_html/real-estate`
`www.mydomain.com/abc` and `mydomain.com/abc` is showing the page properly but not changing url in address bar (it should display `www.mydomain.com/real-estate/abc`)

Comment: What is there in your apache `.conf` for this domain?

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/real-estate
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /real-estate/$1 [NC,L]
```

#### Options

`NC` - Nocase

`QSA` - Append querystring

`L` - Last

`R=301` - Redirect to the url with status code 301

`PT` - Pass through

Comment: Im still getting the same problem `www.mydomain.com` is redirecting to `www.mydomain/home4/xxxxx/public_html/real-estate`

Comment: Test with [R=301,L] in RewriteRule

Comment: And can you please post your apache conf for the same

Comment: I dont know where to get that conf. Im in Shared Hosting